# How to validate a checkbox is checked or not and then performing some action in Cypress?

Tags: checkbox, automation, automated-tests, cypress

```html
<div class="ag-react-container">
 <div class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="" checked=""></div>
</div>
```

```js
cy.("#checkbox").then(($ele) => {
   if($ele.next().is(':checked')){
      cy.("#checkbox").next().should("be.checked");
     }
   else {
     cy.("#checkbox").next().find("input").check();
     cy.("#checkbox").next().find("input").should("be.checked");
     }
  });
```

My problem is the code above is not going into if condition and keeps on executing else condition.

Learning cypress so code can be wrong and would expect correct full code along with some more examples of same if else condition check for buttons, checkboxes or elements.

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be `.next()`. If you remove it, the test works ok.

Also `cy.wrap()` command would be useful to perform multiple steps on `$el`.

```js
cy.get('.ag-react-container')
  .find('input')
  .then($el => {
    if ($el.is(':checked')) {
      cy.wrap($el).should("be.checked")  // passes if checked
    } else {
      cy.wrap($el).click()
      cy.wrap($el).should("be.checked")  // passes if not checked
    }
  })
```

You can also do this

```js
cy.get('.ag-react-container')
  .find('input')
  .then($el => {
    if ($el.is(':not(:checked)')) {
      cy.wrap($el).click()             // checks if not checked
    }
  })
  .should("be.checked")                // passes either way
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your HTML for the checked checkbox you have `checked=""`. So to validate that the checkbox is checked, you have to put in the if condition that element has the attribute checked.

```js
cy.get('input[type="checkbox"]').then(($ele) => {
  if ($ele.attr('checked') == '') {
    //Do Something
  } else {
    //Do Something
  }
})
```